# run process (command) on a remote linux machine from java

Tags: java, linux, communication

I want to run a command in another server from my java code.

Ex. My project runs in under the server ip like ---- xx.xxx.xxx.xx

But I have to run command in another server which is like ---- .yyy.yy.yyy.yy (I am having all the credentials and access for this ip)

Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what all you have tried uptill now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, one of the way:

- On your target server(yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy), run a process that listens for commands from your client machine(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) . There are different ways to communicate between two remote jvms, you may chose any of them for example socket communication.
- On target machine JVM, you can use ProcessBuilder to run the command received from client machine.

Or just some search for frameworks already available to such a task.

Comment: Thanks. Also I need to save my file in that remote server's path. Is this also possible?

Comment: @Mary.Hansen use java based ftp client such as : http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Answer (score 3):

You could do it multiple ways, one way to create your own server client running on both instance and communicate it over some secure protocol to instruct remotely running agent to execute command

and if you don't want to re-invent wheel you can use [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) as underlying communication protocol and using [**sshj**](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) you can connect and execute command on remote machine

---

- [an example code that invokes ping command from remote machine and targetting google.com](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/blob/master/src/main/java/examples/Exec.java)

Comment: Thanks. Also I need to save my file in that remote server's path. Is this also possible?

Comment: you can invoke any command you have access to run as the user access you have, that means you could usually do it easily by running commands